# Snow Leopard Version of XCode

Tags: xcode, version, osx-snow-leopard

I upgraded my system from Leopard to Snow Leopard.  I don't do very much XCode stuff but now I want to build Lua & it is indicating it's wanting XCode 4.1 but they've blocked this off at ADC and are only giving away the Lion version, you have to be a paid registered developer to get any other versions.  It is supposed to be on my Dev Tools DVD that came with snow leopard but I think the DVD may be flaky.   There is a package on there called XCode mpkg but it won't install and the drive makes weird noises.  I should be entitled to this as an owner of Snow Leopard should I not?  How can I get it. There was one site that wanted to sell it to me for $5.99  OK fine but the site said it wouldn't work with my OS version and crashed, so I cant buy it from them even if I want to.   How do you like that for irony?  Can anybody point me to a place where I can get this.  I'll pay the $5.99 if necessary.  Thanks.

Comment: Why not upgrade to Lion? Then it will cost you only $30 for the OS and Xcode is free off of the Mac App Store.

Comment: I probably will before too long here.  I was just hoping not to go through that hassle exactly today.  And I've heard Lion is a little glitchy yet.

Comment: well apparently I can't upgrade to Lion.  My processor isn't "cool" enough.  Not everyone in the world gets a new laptop every six months.  Phooey.

Answer (score 1):

You can download Xcode 3 for OS X Snow Leopard if you register for free at the Apple Developer Connection site [here](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php) (there is a *Looking for Xcode 3?* link in the bottom right part of the page). The pre-release Xcode 4 for Snow Leopard does not appear to be available anymore through the Mac App Store or ADC unless possibly you are a paid member of the Mac Developer program.  Xcode 4.1 is for OS X Lion.

Comment: I found the XCode 3 link hiding at the bottom.  I have downloaded that and installed it with no hassle.  The doc says Leopard, nothing about snow leopard.  We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Apple should be able to provide replacement system disks, although there will be a shipping and handling fee (I'm not sure how much, but I have heard $20 mentioned in some posts on the web):

http://www.apple.com/support/contact/

If you have an Apple store near, might be worth popping in there. Sometimes you can get replacements for free (I suspect this isn't official policy, but depends on the mood of the staff member you talk to...).