# How can i get xCode on a mac OS x snow leopard?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, version, osx-leopard

I would like xCode for C++ programming on my mac but it is a snow leopard and the version in the app store is only for lion and above. Is there a way to get xCode without paying $30 for lion or becoming an apple developer?

Comment: Its Xcode, not xCode or XCode.

Comment: You have more than double the required reputation to fix that yourself, @Just.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Snow Leopard Version of XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919903/snow-leopard-version-of-xcode)

Comment: @RobKennedy If I would fix it, chances are that the OP wouldn't even notice it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Visit the [Apple Developer Website](http://developer.apple.com). There you can download a version Xcode v4.2 for Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

You can download XCode 3 from the apple developer centre if you sign in with a free developer account.

http://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: Is it still there? I just visited and didn't see it.

Comment: You should be able to get Xcode 4.2 with a free account.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is on your Snow Leopard DVD. The version of Xcode that comes with the Snow Leopard DVD should be good enough for C++ programming. You can also go to [connect.apple.com](http://connect.apple.com) to download newer versions of Xcode that run on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

Paying $30 for Lion or getting a free ADC account are the only ways to legally get the current version.  As Mark Syzmczyk mentions, you will also have a copy on your Snow Leopard DVD that will develop Objective-C and C++ software perfectly well with the OS X SDK it was shipped with.